# How to update object except current index in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

```
this.StaticData = {
  "values": [
    {
      "value": "test",
      "label": "test"
    },
    {
      "value": "aa",
      "label": "bb"
    },
    {
      "value": "cc",
      "label": "dd"
    }
  ]
};
```

I have above object of data. I wanted to return all object except `currentIndex`.

**For example  -**

suppose in above objects, if I am going to edit `0th` index values,
and I have updated  `"value": "rest"`, instead of `"value": "test"` and
`"label": "test"` need to keep as it is. So in that case,
it will allow to update the values.

```
{
    "value": "rest",
    "label": "test"
},
```

But if I tried to enter `"label": "bb"` and `"label": "dd"`,
so it will return `false`, because these values are already available in above objects.

```
isLabelExist() {
    const formData = this.editStaticParametersForm.value;
    const currentIndex: number = this.StaticData.values.indexOf(this.selectedRowValue);
    if (formData.label_value && this.StaticData) {
      var isPresent = this.StaticData.values.some(function (el) {
        return el.label === formData.label_value
      });
      if (isPresent) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing can you explain like for given input what output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using find (or some) you can check the "index" (add a second argument to the function find), so,

```
var isPresent = this.StaticData.values.some(function (el,i) {
        return el.label === formData.label_value && i!=currentIndex
      });
```

Really in .ts we use arrow flat and use const or let, not `var`

```
const isPresent = this.StaticData.values.some((el,i)=> {
        return el.label === formData.label_value && i!=currentIndex
      });
```

Or

```
const isPresent = this.StaticData.values.some(
    (el,i)=> el.label === formData.label_value && i!=currentIndex);
```